# How to merge two dataframe with some row values equal?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, inner-join

I have two dataframes which I want to merge into one. The first one has as its columns the ID, while the second has the same values but in the column named id_number. I tried the below code, but in the end the final_df has both ID and the id_number columns and their values. How can I keep only one column for the ids after merging?

```
final_df = df.merge(
    df2,
    left_on='ID',
    right_on='id_number',
    how='inner')
```

Also, let's say the following dataframe format for df column A:

```
A
0
1
2
```

The same column A in the second dataframe has some empty fields, like this:

```
A
-
1
2
```

After merge, how can the final dataframe compound the two dataframes so that A won't have empty values?

Comment: try `final_df.drop(['id_number'], inplace=True)` after merging

Answer (score 0):

try selecting required columns after merge

```
final_df = df.merge(
    df2,
    left_on='ID',
    right_on='id_number',
    how='inner')[['ID', 'col1', 'col2']]
```

or drop the column after merge

```
final_df = df.merge(
    df2,
    left_on='ID',
    right_on='id_number',
    how='inner').drop(['id_number'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution you're looking for:

```py
df.combine_first(df2.rename(columns={'id_number': 'ID'}))
```

A full working example:

```py
import pandas as pd

dfa = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3], 'other': ['A', 'B', 'C']})
dfb = pd.DataFrame({'id_number': [None, 2, 3], 'other_2': ['A2', 'B2', 'C2']})

dfa.combine_first(dfb.rename(columns={'id_number': 'ID'}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename 'on-the-fly' `id_number` column of `df2` to `ID`

```
final_df = df.merge(
    df2.rename(columns={'id_number': 'ID'}),
    on='ID',
    how='inner')
```